# Recreating "Font" Property Behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, intellisense, web-controls, system.componentmodel

Controls that inherit off of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl` have a property called `Font`. The type is `System.Web.Ui.WebControls.FontInfo`.

When working with these controls in the designer, it breaks out the `Font` property into multiple properties like `Font-Bold`, `Font-Italic`, etc. When working with these same WebControls in the codebehind, there's only a `Font` property (no `Font-Bold`, `Font-Italic`, etc).

How can this behavior be manually recreated when creating WebControls? Specifically, what combination of `System.ComponentModel` attributes can show/hide these properties in Intellisense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property that you'd like to expand (`Font` in this case) should have attribute `System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility` set to `System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content`. This is detailed in the following link

[System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibility.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access Bold, Italic and so on as boolean properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fontinfo.aspx

```
  void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // When the page loads, set the the myLabel Label control's FontInfo properties.
    // Note that myLabel.Font is a FontInfo object.

    myLabel.Font.Bold = true;
    myLabel.Font.Italic = false;
    myLabel.Font.Name = "verdana";
    myLabel.Font.Overline = false;
    myLabel.Font.Size = 10;
    myLabel.Font.Strikeout = false;
    myLabel.Font.Underline = true;

    // Write information on the FontInfo object to the myLabel label.
    myLabel.Text = myLabel.Font.ToString();

  }
```

Comment: right. But the Font property doesn't show up in designer mode, only in the code behind. Additionally, Font-Bold, Font-Italic, etc don't show up on the code behind, only on the designer mode. I want to be able to create properties on my webcontrols that behave that way.

Answer (score 1):

The property-breakdown is happening automatically.

If you have a control that has a property that has properties of its own

```
public class ServerControl1 : WebControl
{
   public CompositeItem Composite { get; set; }

    public ServerControl1()
    {
        Composite = new CompositeItem();
    }
}

public class CompositeItem
{
    public bool ItemOne { get; set; }
    public string ItemTwo { get; set; }
    public int ItemThree { get; set; }
}
```

you can use the Font-Bold syntax in the aspx, meaning that

```
<cc:ServerControl1 runat="server" ID="scOne" 
    Composite-ItemOne="true" Composite-ItemTwo ="stringx"/>
```

will work as expected. However, autocomplete does not work, and I'm not sure which combination of `System.ComponentModel` attributes is required to make it behave like the Font-Bold.

Comment: Ah~ I didn't know it was automatic that it would provide those extended properties. Indeed the question at this point is what combination of `System.ComponentModel` attributes would lead to the behavior found in webcontrols inheriting off of `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl`